# multiple ndb.model class in google app engine with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new to GAE and Python and I am working through the tutorials google provide, however the problem comes when I try and create more than 1 model class in the same file. If I add something like this:

```
class Greeting(ndb.Model):
    """Models an individual Guestbook entry with author, content, and date."""
    author = ndb.UserProperty()
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    colours = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)

class UserInformation(ndb.model):
    username = ndb.UserProperty()
    firstname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    lastname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    telephone = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

I get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler

    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject

    obj = __import__(path[0])

  File "C:\Python27\gae\listproperty\main.py", line 37, in <module>

    class UserInformation(ndb.model):

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases

    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

If I put the UserInformation class into a second file and try and import it into main.py I get a similar error message again.

My question is what is the best way to handle multiple ndb.model class in GAE using Python?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a typo, change the line:

```
class UserInformation(ndb.model):
```

to (notice the capital `M`):

```
class UserInformation(ndb.Model):
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: Incredible! Thanks for your help